# Get sqlite icu tokenizer for python3 on OpenShift

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, openshift, fts3

I'm using FTS3 sqlite tables in my Python3 application running on OpenShift. Unfortunately, the python3.3 installation includes an sqlite3 module without the "uci" tokenizer. How can I use uci-tokenized FTS3 tables in this case? The "unicode61" tokenizer would be ok, too, but the sqlite version is too old (3.6.20) to support that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get an up to date sqlite version seems to be using [apsw](https://github.com/rogerbinns/apsw%20apsw) instead of the sqlite3 module from the standard library. By building it with `python setup.py fetch --all --missing-checksum-ok  build --enable-all-extensions install test` a recent sqlite version is downloaded and compiled into the module including all extensions.